# This happened when i updated the project to Flutter 2.0 and updated all packages to latest version

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, cocoapods

Before answering Please note that i have tried all these solutions:
sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean
pod deintegrate
pod cache clean --all
Follow this command on project folder:
flutter clean
rm ios/Podfile && flutter build ios
(I've also uncommented this line in pod File [platform :ios, '12.0'])

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
In Podfile:
firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
Firebase/Analytics (~> 6.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/Core (= 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.0.0)

```
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
  Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.3.0)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FirebaseCore":
In Podfile:
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
FirebaseCore (= 7.3.0)

```
firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
  Firebase/Crashlytics (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
    FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
      FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
```

CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "nanopb":
In Podfile:
firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 1.0.4, which depends on
Firebase/CoreOnly (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
FirebaseCore (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 7.0) was resolved to 7.9.0, which depends on
nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)

```
firebase_crashlytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_crashlytics/ios`) was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends on
  Firebase/Crashlytics (= 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
    FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 7.3.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
      nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
```

Comment: did u find any solution ? I m stuck since few hours on this

Answer (score 0):

I found a soluton:

- delete podfile.lock, podfile, pod folder, Runner.xcworkspace in your ios folder
  [Run the following command in terminal from your ios directory i.e
  (If you are in your project directory type :
- cd ios )]
- flutter clean
- pod install
- flutter run
  (Hope this will solve your problem, Remember ***pod install will take a lot of time - be patient)

Answer (score 0):

First clean flutter project

```
flutter clean
rm -Rf ios/Pods
rm -Rf ios/.symlinks
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -Rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec
```

For clean pod file

```
rm ios/Podfile
```

Then run your flutter project

```
flutter run -v
```